# esp32 with Neo6M gps gives no data

Tags: serial, esp32, gps

I am simply using the following code

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // set the data rate for the HardwareSerial port
  Serial2.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial2.available() > 0)
    Serial.write(Serial2.read());
}
```

the Connection is as follows 
pin 16(D27) of esp32 - > Tx of Neo6M
pin 17(D14) of esp32 - > Rx of Neo6M

Now I am not getting any data in the serial monitor. The same module works with arduino with software serial.
I am completely new in this thing and office is keep asking about the progess.

Comment: What exact ESP32 board do you have, and why have you tagged the question "Arduino UNO"? Is there an Uno in the mix as well?

Comment: I am using esp32 dev module. I tagged uno as the same pattern worked in uno. No uno is associated.  so let me remove it.  this one I am using : https://lastminuteengineers.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ESP32-Hardware-Specifications-USB-to-TTL-Converter.jpg

Comment: The default baud rate for the Neo-6M is 9600, not 115200. Have you reconfigured it to work at 115200 baud?

Comment: Did not noticed that. But I just modified the baud rate and still nothing. current baud rate is 9600

Comment: The pins you are using are the ones actually labelled TX2 and RX2?

Comment: Yes that I can check from the librarary too. But should not they work simply? I mean I lost here completely.

Comment: are you suggesting me to connect me the module 6M with TX2 and RX2 ? Sorry for souding dumb but my office is keep asking I am loosing myself too.

Comment: The default pins for Serial2 are GPIO16 and GPIO17 (D16 and D17) not pins 16 and pin 17. Those pins are helpfully labelled TX2 and RX2.

Comment: okay! so I have connected the Tx of neo6m to rx2 and Rx of neo 6M to tx2. hope this is the wiring?  now the same code in with baudrate 9600 is uploaded. still nothing. I should get NMEA raw data in the serial monitor?

Comment: As long as you have power and ground connected too, that should be fine. There are other possible baud rates that could be configured on your module as default - you could try 4800, 38400 or 57600.

Comment: I guess the esp32 3.3v is not sufficient to power up the neo6m

Comment: It's possible. I am not sure off hand how much it needs. It shoudn't need much, it's receive only.